# how to solve cannot find Cannot find module '../home/featuredRooms' or its corresponding type declarations.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I am getting this weird error,when i deploy my site to netlify or vercel, but this project runs correctly in my computer. I am using typescript with next js. I Also tried to rename folders to lowercase

Here is the github link:- https://github.com/Sumukha210/hotel-booking

```
    Error occurred prerendering page "/gallery". Read more: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
23:50:55.380    TypeError: pathname.replaceAll is not a function
```

Comment: did you used absolute imports before?

Comment: Do you get the same error locally when you run `yarn build`?

Comment: I didn't get any error when I run the yarn build command, it works fune

Comment: That's a completely different issue from what you originally asked, though. You should create a new question rather than editing your old one.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual path in the file system is `../Home/featuredRooms`.

You're most likely using a macOS device locally, where paths are case-insensitive so no issues occur. However, when deployed to your hosting services Linux machines with case-sensitive paths are used, so `../home/featuredRooms` will not be valid.

As a general rule of thumb I'd suggest you always use lowercase folder/file names to avoid these kind of issues.